# Query to get first login of every user

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Lets say we have a simple database table `AUDIT_LOG` containing columns `EMPLOYEE_ID` and `LOGIN_DTTM`.

We want only to retrieve the first login of all users that logged in for the day. How can you make a query that does this?

We are using Oracle 12c

Comment: Have you tried to group by AUDIT_LOG filter for today entries and select min LOGIN_DTTM?

Comment: What is the datatype of `LOGIN_DTTM` and what have you tried so far?

Comment: datatype is DATE

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:  It is still unclear what are the columns available in the table  and what you are expecting to see in the output. I must modify the query I had written earlier as these things are uncertain yet.

I suggested you to use the `FIRST`  function: Refer  [**FIRST**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm)

and also to  include the `WHERE` clause only to select the records for the current day ( or any other day if you like )  query where x is any column that you need to get the value for first login.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
         MAX (x) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LOGIN_DTTM) as first_x
    FROM AUDIT_LOG
    WHERE LOGIN_DTTM >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID
```

However, if you simply want an output like the below.

```
| EMPLOYEE_ID |          FIRST_LOGIN |
|-------------|----------------------|
|           1 | 2018-03-05T08:01:01Z |
|           2 | 2018-03-05T08:01:02Z |
|           3 | 2018-03-05T08:01:03Z |
```

a simple `MIN` with group by would work for you as suggested by Alex.

**Query2**

```
  SELECT employee_id, MIN (login_dttm) AS first_login
    FROM audit_log
   WHERE login_dttm >= TRUNC (SYSDATE)
GROUP BY employee_id;
```

you have only  said "it has other fields in the query like employee details (name, address, tel no)". If so, what kind of output are you expecting? Make it clear in your question so that we could assist you to provide the correct solution. As said earlier, It is not easy to simply guess and provide you the right solution you are expecting without knowing what you wish to see.

Comment: it says ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: @HingleMcJingleberry : I think you made a mistake while constructing your query. You should include all the columns you selected in `group by`. Google GROUP BY in sql to understand how `group by` works. The query which i have posted here is working fine as you can see in the sqlfiddle demo.

Comment: what it has other fields in the query like employee details (name, address, tel no)

Comment: `MIN (LOGIN_DTTM) as first_login` would give the same result; what is the `KEEP` clause adding here? (I'd also do `LOGIN_DTTM >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)` so any index on that column could still be used.)

Comment: @HingleMcJingleberry : You very first line of the question contradicts what you are saying. That's the reason It is always advised that you post the sample data and expected result and what you tried to help us to provide a right solution. Giving incomplete information and expecting us to guess what you actually want is not helpful.

Comment: @AlexPoole : I pasted the wrong code assuming another output. I will post the correct one with the changes.

Comment: what it has other fields in the query like employee details (name, address, tel no). Would the same query work? and jus add other fields in the group by

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first login time for each employee then it's simple aggregation:

```
select employee_id,
  min (login_dttm) as first_login_dttm
from audit_log
where login_dttm >= trunc(sysdate)
group by employee_id;
```

If you want other columns from the table from the rows with those earliest login times, as suggested in comments, you can either use [`keep ... dense_rank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/FIRST.html) (as @Kaushik originally suggested for the simple scenario):

```
select employee_id,
  min (login_dttm) as first_login_dttm,
  min (some_col) keep (dense_rank first order by login_dttm) as first_some_col
from audit_log
where login_dttm >= trunc(sysdate)
group by employee_id;
```

with a separate `min (...) keep (dense_rank first order by login_dttm)` for each of the columns you want, or - and this may be clearer if there are a lot of columns you want - use a subquery to assign [an analytic rank](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/RANK.html) to each row, and only keep the first (corresponding to the earliest login time):

```
select employee_id, login_dttm, some_col
from (
  select employee_id, login_dttm, some_col,
    rank() over (partition by employee_id order by login_dttm) as rnk
  from audit_log
  where login_dttm >= trunc(sysdate)
)
where rnk = 1;
```

(This assumes an employee won't have two logins in the same second; if they did they would rank the same. If that scenario is possible you would need to use `dense_rank()` instead and decide how you want to break ties.)